# How to add an eventlistener for items has no specified id or class_

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have an userscript it works correctly when i click on +1 button ( I created it) it make get and post calls. But i need watch website's send message button.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" disabled="">Send message</button>
```

is the button and the btn and btn-primary class added to other buttons too.

Im doing the actions on the ButtonClickAction function. How can i watch the clicks on the Send message button.

Is any solution for watch this button ?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Emre's Users Script.
// @description Example Script.
// @match       *://example.com*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant      GM.xmlHttpRequest
// @version    0.1 - Alpha
// ==/UserScript==

/*--- Create a button in a container div.  It will be styled and
    positioned with CSS.
*/

var zNode = document.createElement ('div');
zNode.innerHTML = '<button id="myButton" type="button">'
                + '+1 EKLE</button><div style="color: white;" id="mydiv">Yükleniyor</div><div  style="color: white;font-size: 14px;" id="mydiv1"></div> '
                ;
zNode.setAttribute ('id', 'myContainer');
document.body.appendChild (zNode);
GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://example.com/ajax.php?id=21",
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "Accept": "text/xml"
  },
  onload: function(response) {

 document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = response.responseText;

  }
});
GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://example.com/ajax.php?aylik=buay",
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "Accept": "text/xml"
  },
  onload: function(response) {

 document.getElementById("mydiv1").innerHTML = response.responseText;

  }
});
//--- Activate the newly added button.
document.getElementById ("myButton").addEventListener (
    "click", ButtonClickAction, false
);




function ButtonClickAction (zEvent) {
    /*--- For our dummy action, we'll just add a line of text to the top
        of the screen.
    */
    /*var zNode = document.createElement ('p');
    zNode.innerHTML = 'The button was clicked.';
    document.getElementById ("myContainer").appendChild (zNode);*/
GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://example.com/ajax.php?ekle=1&id=21",
  data: "username=johndoe&password=xyz123zz",

  onload: function(response) {
  document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = response.responseText;
  },
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  }
});
    GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://example.com/ajax.php?aylik=buay",
  headers: {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
    "Accept": "text/xml"
  },
  onload: function(response) {

 document.getElementById("mydiv1").innerHTML = response.responseText;

  }
});
}

//--- Style our newly added elements using CSS.
GM_addStyle ( `
    #myContainer {
            position: fixed;
    bottom: 9px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #e91e63;
    border: 3px outset black;
    margin: 5px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 1100;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    }
    #myButton {
        cursor:                 pointer;
margin-left: 23px;
    }
    #myContainer p {
        color:                  red;
        background:             white;
    }
` );
```

Anyone will help ? Im stucked since 20 days..

Comment: How do you want to show the number on the button? Should it replace the `Add +1` text? Can it be clicked multiple times?

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you check it again?

Comment: Is anyone have a solution ?